# SQL detect changes in log stored in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have db log of items prices. Sometimes ( usually every month ) new State with prices stored into db. 
Each item has uniqueid. It doen't change from month to month.

I've build sample database:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0bc28/3

I need to detect item price changes. For example
If item1 price on 2013-01-01 was 122, on 2013-02-01 was 122, on 2013-03-01 was 124

Select should show 1 row 
itemname = item1,  oldPrice = 122,  newPrice = 124, dateCHanged = 2013-03-01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
with x as (
    select i.*, s.datecreated, row_number() over (partition by uniqueid order by datecreated) as rn
    from items i
    inner join states s on i.stateid = s.id
)
select x1.uniqueId, x1.price as oldPrice, x2.price as newPrice, x2.dateCreated as dateChanged
from x x1
inner join x x2 on x1.uniqueid = x2.uniqueid
--and datediff(month, x1.datecreated, x2.datecreated) = 1
and x1.rn - x2.rn = 1
and x1.price <> x2.price
```

Comment: not bad, but sometimes it's not every month and can be uploaded more orr less frequent